# Trouble sorting arrays with vectors in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to make a program where the use enters the name of a student and the test score. The program will return the scores graded on a curve along with the name of the student that should receive that grade. The problem I'm running into is that the paired arrays only output -858993460 below is my code any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
int main()
{
const int MAX = 300;
int n;
int y;
int x; // find what the difference between the highest score and 100
std::vector<std::pair < std::string, int>> vect;

//Asks for # of tests for loop
std::cout << "Hello, How many tests do you need to grade?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> n;
std::cout << "Please enter a grade then press enter. Repeat until you have 
reached the number specified in the previous step" << std::endl;
std::cout << "DO NOT ENTER DECIMALS" << std::endl;
// declare array
std::string name[MAX];
int score[MAX];

//pairs arrays
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    vect.push_back(make_pair(name[i], score[i]));
}

// gets input for names and test scores
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::cin >> name[i] >> score[i];


}




// sorts tests
std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end()); 


//add a space for easier reading
std::cout << " " << std::endl;
//finds the difference between the highest scores and 0
x = 100 - vect[0].second;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    std::cout << vect[i].first << vect[i].second + x << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "enter a value then press enter to close";
    std::cin >> y;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are pushing uninitalized score values to `vect`. When you read the actual values with `cin`, it only updates `score[i]`, not the pair in `vect`.

Comment: You take two books, make a copy of each page from each book, and then combine the two pages into a third book, that contains each page from the first two books. Only after you create the third book, you go back and scribble over the pages in one of the first books. Do you expect to see what you scribbled over, in the third book? Replace the first two books with your arrays, and the third book with your vector of pairs, and you should be able to figure it where you went wrong, all by yourself.

Comment: A `std::vector` stores copies.  In your second loop, `names[i]` and `scores[i]` is not magically going to change the `pair` item you placed in the vector in the previous loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `vect.push_back(make_pair(name[i], score[i]));` it creates new objects in array, there is no reference with `std::string name[MAX];` and    `int score[MAX];`. So when you do input `std::cin >> name[i] >> score[i];` you change `name` array and `score` array, your vector(`vect`) stays uninitialized.
You need to create temporary `std::pair < std::string, int> pair_input;` and push_back to vect it each iteration, like this:

```
// gets input for names and test scores
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::pair < std::string, int> pair_input;
    std::cin >> pair_input.first >> pair_input.second;
    vect.push_back(pair_input);
}
```

Remove part of pushing back, where you were initializing your vector before:

```
//    //pairs arrays
//    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
//    {
//        vect.push_back(make_pair(name[i], score[i]));
//    }
```

because we will do push_back to vector each input operation. After all changes your code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 300;
    int n;
    int y;
    int x; // find what the difference between the highest score and 100
    std::vector<std::pair < std::string, int>> vect;

    //Asks for # of tests for loop
    std::cout << "Hello, How many tests do you need to grade?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "Please enter a grade then press enter. Repeat until you havereached the number specified in the previous step" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "DO NOT ENTER DECIMALS" << std::endl;

    // gets input for names and test scores
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::pair < std::string, int> pair_input;
        std::cin >> pair_input.first >> pair_input.second;
        vect.push_back(pair_input);
    }

    // sorts tests
    std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());

    //add a space for easier reading
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    //finds the difference between the highest scores and 0
    x = 100 - vect[0].second;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vect[i].first << vect[i].second + x << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "enter a value then press enter to close";
    std::cin >> y;
    return 0;
}
```

While I was testing I got this output result:

```
Hello, How many tests do you need to grade?
2
Please enter a grade then press enter. Repeat until you havereached the number specified in the previous step
DO NOT ENTER DECIMALS
test
2
test3
3

test100
test3101
enter a value then press enter to close
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help I'm fairly new and appreciate everyone input. Thank you again.

Comment: @Nathan Not at all! I hope you understood your problem clearly.